# Node, MongoDB : Incrementing values of items in array with range query

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I have an array of categories under users collection in mongodb.

Basically there is a drag and drop menu of categories in front end, when a drag&drop happens I want to update the database. Since it is not possible to move items in array, I decided to give them a position value "pos" in mongodb and sort them later in angularjs.

```js
categories: [
    {
        "_id" : ObjectId("5776782a57c9580256536656"),
        "title" : "Cars",
        "url" : "cars",
        "pos" : 0
    },
    {
        "_id" : ObjectId("5776786afdcd6ed056edff25"),
        "title" : "Photography",
        "url" : "photography",
        "nodes" : [ 
            {
                "_id" : ObjectId("57767870fdcd6ed056edff26"),
                "title" : "Landscape",
                "url" : "landscape"
            }
        ],
        "pos" : 1
    },
    {
        "_id" : ObjectId("adf9845782578a376161d079"),
        "title" : "Travel",
        "url" : "travel",
        "pos" : 2
    }
]
```

I'm using nodejs-express as server and here is my code to move categories.

- oldIndex : position of category before moving
- newIndex : new position of category after moving
- userId : users object Id

```js
    if (newIndex>oldIndex){
        db.collection('users').updateOne({ "_id": userId, "categories.pos": { $gte: oldIndex, $lt: newIndex } }, { $inc : { "categories.$.pos" : -1 } }, function (err, res) {
            console.log(res);
            if (err) callback(0)
            else {
                db.collection('users').updateOne(filter, { $set :  cdata }, function (err, res) {
                    if (err) callback(0);
                    callback(1);
                });
            }
        });
    } else {
        db.collection('users').updateOne({ "_id": userId, "categories.pos": { $gt: newIndex, $lte: oldIndex  } }, { $inc : { "categories.$.pos" : 1 } }, function (err, res) {
            console.log(res);
            if (err) callback(0)
            else {
                db.collection('users').updateOne(filter, { $set :  cdata }, function (err, res) {
                    if (err) callback(0);
                    callback(1);
                });
            }
        });
    }
```

basically, the code meant to do this

**if (newIndex > oldIndex)**

- Category A - 0 (oldIndex)
- Category B - 1
- Category C - 2
- Category D - 3

to move A to Index 2

- Category B - 0 (-1)
- Category C - 1 (-1)
- Category A - 2 (newIndex)
- Category D - 3 (0)

and the other way around

**if (oldIndex > newIndex)**

- Category A - 0
- Category B - 1
- Category C - 2 (oldIndex)
- Category D - 3

to move C to Index 0

- Category C - 0 (newIndex)
- Category A - 1 (+1)
- Category B - 2 (+1)
- Category D - 3 (0)

In this case, I can't run a find query to see & troubleshoot the results of the query..

with any number of categories, query only updates one value.

I guess I need new pair of eyes.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

MongoDB keeps the order of the array. 
So what about remove the element in the array and reinsert the element with the correct position by using `$position`

Query for remove the element:

```
db.getCollection('users').update({
        "_id" : idusers
    },
    {
        $pull: {
            categories: {
                field: foo //your field for grep the element
            }
        }
})
```

And the query for set the element at his new index:

```
db.getCollection('users').update(
    {
        "_id" : idusers
    },
    {
        $push: {
            categories: {
               // Set just one element in the $each, that enable you to use $position
                $each: [{
                    "title" : "Photography",
                    "url" : "photography",
                    "nodes" : [{
                            "_id" : ObjectId("57767870fdcd6ed056edff26"),
                            "title" : "Landscape",
                            "url" : "landscape"
                    }]
                }],
                $position: newIndex
            }
        }
    }
)
```

I made some manually test and that seem to work

Comment: Thanks for the answer, appreciated 

In case of a category with many sub categories it would be bad for performance I guess. Right now I am sending the id of the category and the old/new indexes from client, so the request is very short, 

This way I have to send all json of the moved Item from client or make a find query to get the category by id first. Yesterday to cut short I made it to send whole categories json from client to server to update, your solution is the better alternative way right now.

Comment: Accept the answer for close the question if you think that solved your problem.